# The variable is either undeclared or was never assigned warning

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the base class:

```
public class BaseClass : UserControl
{
     protected ListView list;
     protected TreeView tree;
    
     public BaseClass()
     {
         //...
     }
     //...
}
```

Child class:

```
public partial class MyClass : BaseClass
{
     public MyClass()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.BackColor = VisualStyleInformation.TextControlBorder;
         this.Padding = new Padding(1);
     }
     //...
}
    
partial class MyClass
{
    //...
        
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
         this.tree = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
         this.list = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
         //...
         this.tree.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 23);
         this.tree.Name = "blablabla";
    }
}
```

Compiling the classes gives me these warnings:

```
Warning 1 The variable 'tree' is either undeclared or was never assigned.
Warning 2 The variable 'list' is either undeclared or was never assigned.
```

What am I doing wrong? These variables are declared in base class and assigned in child class.

Comment: That's a designer issue.  Re-build your solution and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Side-note: imho it's more readable to write `base.tree` instead of `this.tree` here.

Comment: I don't see any problem with those fields. But you must decide if `MyClass` is `public` or not. The two `partial class` declaration must agree.

Comment: never-assigned is a proper warning for the BaseClass. It looks like it should be abstract.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Imho, one should only use the `base` keyword when this type overrides (or hides) a member from the base class. In this case, the member is just inherited, so I think `this.tree` (or just `tree` with no specification of what instance) is best.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Altough no access modifier means most restrictive accessibility which is public when the other part of the class is public.

Comment: @HenkHolterman But it's just a field. It can't be abstract (unless it's changed to a property).

Comment: @jeppe - the class (BaseClass) can be abstract.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, warnings not for the BaseClass for MyClass when I try to add controls: `this.Controls.Add(this.tree)` . It can't be abstract, but it has virtual functions

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are right; I didn't know that. I thought the second "part" was declared (implicitly) `internal`, and therefore inconsistent with the first part, but I was wrong.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: You'll get a compile time exception if they would have different access modifiers. But i must admit that i also didn't know that C# defaults to the other parts accessibility on partial classes. I had to test it.

Comment: @William I tested your code and It works fine, as said SLaks try to rebuild the project and restart VS.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: IMHO `tree` would be better than either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question lacks an *answer*, so here goes...

**Rebuild Solution then restart Visual Studio** worked for me :-)

Thanks to [**SLaks**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) for his comment above.

Also discussed at:

[stackoverflow.com - The variable 'variable_name' is either undeclared or was never assigned.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521600/the-variable-variable-name-is-either-undeclared-or-was-never-assigned)

[social.msdn.microsoft.com - The variable 'control_name' is either undeclared or was never assigned.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4718ac1f-7443-423c-81d2-25059fec444d/the-variable-controlname-is-either-undeclared-or-was-never-assigned#0ececae7-fc50-4257-b80b-aecce43fb9ab)

Comment: My `UserControl` constructor was expecting a value.  If I passed in a reference to a `static readonly` member variable, the designer would throw an exception (*The variable is either undeclared or was never assigned*).  Unfortunately the above fix does not work for me in *CSharp* (*Visual Studio 2013*).  Ended up moving the input parameter to an `Initialize` method that I added to the `UserControl`.  Interestingly enough, if I simply instantiated the required type directly into the constructor's input parameter, everything was ok: `this.myControl = new MyUserControl(new CustomType());`

Comment: @Pressacco interesting... sounds like another question.

Comment: For me, this error went away when I changed Solution Platforms from Mixed Platforms to Any CPU.

Comment: This issue happened to me because I was building for x64 but the Visual Studio designer is hosted in-process in Visual Studio which is still a 32-bit process (even VS2017). After rebuilding for x86 and reloading the designer it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this with the designer and the main cause each time was the fact my solution was set for x64 output.  Currently, the designer CANNOT deal with a control in a solution set for x64, so you need to change it to Any CPU, make your edits, then change it back to x64 to do your running/debugging.